# pgAdmin tools for postgreSQL cannot connect to PostgreSQL on a Windows 10 local machine

Tags: pgadmin-4, postgresql-10

I have just installed PostgreSQL 10 on a Windows 10 machine. When I start pgAdmin version 4 i get an error namely "The application server could not be contacted". I have also noted that the "postgresql-x64-10 - PostgreSQL Server 10" service fails to start when I try and start it under services.

Comment: Looks like the Server is not running

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by the 'server is not running'. As I said, when I try to start the postgre service, it starts and then it stops.

Comment: Do you un it as a servcie or how do you start it?

Comment: I am trying to start it by right clicking on it and choosing 'start'. from the services module.

Comment: Take a look into the eventview to see if you get any error

Comment: The event viewer says Timed out waiting for server startup

Comment: Maybe the port is in use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179390/discussion-between-khandakhulu-and-jens).

Answer (score 0):

By typing

netstat -aon

in cmd prompt you get the PIDs of processes working and also on which port they are

simply search for the process allocated to port 5432.
since, postgresql installation is commonly installed on that port.

end the task from the details tab of task manager by clicking on PID to arrange them ascending or descending.

then try running pgadmin. it surely works then